# Enabling <> for headers in g++

Tags: include, g++

I'm having an issue getting some code to work.  Is there a way to enable headers to be included like so

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
```

Instead of

```
#include "boost/asio.hpp"
```

Comment: I've never had to do something like that.  Can you post a bit more code and the error you're getting?  #include <> worked for me always.  Try #include <stdio.h> or #include <list>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the directory to be searched for that path after `-I` on the command line to gcc.